# How can password_verify and doveadm pw -t verify a password without salt

Tags: php, hash, salt, verify

im currently trying to understand hashes and salts. As i understand it, it should not be possible to verify a password, if i only have the password and the generated hash(that was generated with a random salt ofc).
So how can the `password_verify` function in **PHP** verify my **password**, if i dont give it the salt? Is there a hidden variable in the background, that stores it for the **php** hashing functions?

And if that is the case, how can

```
doveadm pw -t '{SHA512-CRYPT}$6$myhash...' -p "qwertz"
```

verify it too, even if i run it on a complety different computer? Thats a tool, that comes with Dovecot(a MDA).

Here is my PHP code, that creates a random salt with 64 chars, combines it with a password, creates a hash and verifies the hash via `password_verify()`.

I just started working on the whole `hash/salt/pepper` thing today, so there could be a huge flaw in my whole train of thought.

```
<?php
$password = "qwertz";
$salt = createSalt(64);
$hash = crypt($password, "$6$$salt");

if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
}


function createSalt($length){
    $chars = "IrhsYyLofUKj4caz0FDBCe2W9NRunTgQvp7qOXmS5GM3EJV6i8tAHdkPbxwl1Z";
    $salt="";
    for($i=0; $i < $length; $i++){
        $newchar = substr($chars, rand(0,strlen($chars)-1),1);
        $salt .= $newchar;
    }
    return $salt;
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't think your $salt is in action as you use $6$$salt

Comment: `password_hash` and `password_verify` do not require you to salt the password yourself. This is handled internally and is returned as part of the resulting hash. Those two functions are designed to be idiot-proof :)

Comment: @MdMonjurUlHasan Monjur Ul Hasan $6$ was in there for another reason, same outcome without it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hash contains several pieces of information. This [article](https://www.aychedee.com/2012/03/14/etc_shadow-password-hash-formats/) explains the format used by Unix but I believe PHP password functions use a similar format (if not the same):

> The hash field itself is comprised of three different fields. They are
>   separated by '$' and represent:
>
> - Some characters which represents the cryptographic hashing mechanism used to generate the actual hash
> - A randomly generated salt to safeguard against rainbow table attacks
> - The hash which results from joining the users password with the stored salt and running it through the hashing mechanism specified in
>     the first field

It can also include the exact per-algorithm options used to generate the hash, such us the algorithmic cost:

```
var_dump(password_hash('foo', PASSWORD_BCRYPT, [
    'cost' => 8,
]));
```

> ```
> string(60) "$2y$08$7Z5bTz7xXnom8QsrbZ7uQetMLxOZ7WjuDkUYRIh73Ffa17GV1Tb7q"
> ```

Here `$2y$08$` means that Bcrypt with cost 8 was used.

If we use the newer Argon2 available in PHP/7.2 there're even more params:

```
$argon2i$v=19$m=1024,t=2,p=2$YzJBSzV4TUhkMzc3d3laeg$zqU/1IN0/AogfP4cmSJI1vc8lpXRW9/S0sYY2i2jHT0
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. In my case, the salt is always 16 bytes long and stored in between the  second and the third $.                                    $6$wMW8ASRU7sv3Wims$uMyN6a3UF/7SEVefsriAqCB3bPxynZ6zsuwV68tURvIyZhSKYO.1DIh9kRTzfBC6rnZiRiwrJ71/gBBtWHWfj0 -
 - wMW8ASRU7sv3Wims appears to be the salt.

Answer (score 3):

Some backgrounds to the answer from @Álvaro González :

PHP manual suggests using "password_hash" instead of "crypt" function through "password_hash" is a "crypt()" wrapper ( Because, it uses a strong hash, generates a strong salt, and applies proper rounds automatically. )

"password_hash()" returns the algorithm, cost, and salt as part of the returned hash. Therefore, all information that's needed to verify the hash is included in it. This allows the "password_verify" function to verify the hash without needing separate storage for the salt or algorithm information. : http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Since, "password_hash" is a wrapper for "crypt", "crypt" also does the same, ie., returns the algorithm, cost, and salt as part of the returned hash. and thus "password_verify" can verify the hash.

Now, please check the answer given by @Álvaro González